# ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'ipopt' in Pyomo

Tags: python, executable, pyomo, ipopt

I am learning Pyomo and trying to use ipopt to solve an example question. but initially, I have installed package, then it always shows that there is not a ipopt found. After that, I reinstalled many time, now it shows that

```
'''WARNING: Could not locate the 'ipopt' executable, which is required for solver
    ipopt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ApplicationError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2e55f87657f9> in <module>
      1 model.N=50
      2 instance = model.create_instance()
----> 3 results = opt.solve(instance) # solves and updates instance

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py in solve(self, *args, **kwds)
    514         """ Solve the problem """
    515 
--> 516         self.available(exception_flag=True)
    517         #
    518         # If the inputs are models, then validate that they have been

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py in available(self, exception_flag)
    116             if exception_flag:
    117                 msg = "No executable found for solver '%s'"
--> 118                 raise ApplicationError(msg % self.name)
    119             return False
    120         return True

ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'ipopt'
'''**bold**
```

*italic*

> quote

I have no idea how to fix it and I installed anaconda in desk D instead of C. Could anyone please help me, I need it for an assignment and exam in a month. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make sure you've read the guidelines for posting questions. As a rule of thumbs, post data and the attemps you've done to solve or answer your questions.

Comment: How did you install it? Windows Command line, or Anaconda Command line, or some other OS command line?

Comment: Hi, Dustin I supposed to install it with Anaconda Command line

Comment: Is there already a solution to this issue?

Comment: It is running for me in Windows, but not in Mac OS.

Comment: Dear Zhao, could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been solved by installing the latest version of anacondo and the 3.11 version of ipopt

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem after installing 3.13.1. What I did is just to download 3.11.1, then save ipopt.exe in
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin

Then it works.

Comment: Hi Xu Meng, Thanks for your suggestion, but it does not work for me. It still shows that @Solver (ipopt) returned non-zero return code (3221225501)                                                 Do you have any idea on this?

Answer (score 3):

For mac users:

1. Install homebrew in the terminal by: 
   *`rm -fr $(brew --repo homebrew/core)`*
   *`brew tap homebrew/core`*
2. Install ipopt by:
   *`brew install ipopt`*
3. Restart your IDE.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. May I ask what is brew? The terminal does not response to brew comment

Answer (score 2):

install this version:
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 ipopt

from this link:
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ipopt

Comment: Add details if solution worked for you and was it the exactly same issue you tried for

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30938456)

Answer (score 1):

Please, check this discussion https://github.com/conda-forge/ipopt-feedstock/issues/55 . I reported the same issue.
Perhaps, you should downgrade IPOPT version to the supported one (v3.11.1).

Comment: Hi, ab123

I tried to installed V3.11.1, but it shows IPOPT does not exist

Comment: this is the exact comment from the mentioned issue https://github.com/conda-forge/ipopt-feedstock/issues/55#issuecomment-734702894